# Safe way to install Ubuntu - without modifying existing OS to test for drivers and development applications

Tags: drivers, gpu-driver

I am using Lenovo G770 and doing android development. Not very happy with certain graphics drivers of my system as they are not using the full potential. 
I want to switch to ubuntu and first I want to install it temporarily just to ensure that drivers etc and hardware has no conflict and once happy I will install it on my drive.

So my question is what is the best way to install without disturbing my existing widows installation or my boot manager, so that I can check Ubuntu works best for my hardware ?

Is the Usb install going to be best ? will it allow me to install third party drivers for my laptop  alogn with applications such as android studio etc on the USB ? Or is it a read only install ??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have to install Ubuntu to test drivers for your hardware. You can download the ISO files and create an installation USB (or DVD) and use it to "Try Ubuntu without Installing" option. Most drivers are in there.If something does not work, then search here about getting that specific hardware to work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu: Best to make a Full install to USB if you are testing drivers, some drivers do not work on a Live USB, (ie Nvidia). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-19-10-to-usb-device-step-by-step. Safest to unplug the HDD before proceeding.